# Unable to Git push to a remote branch (not master) from azure pipeline

Tags: bash, git, github, azure-devops

I have been trying to do a Git Push from a bash task on Azure DevOps. I was already pushing the code to the master branch without any issues.
But now I have to push it to the dev branch, and for some reason, Git Pull works but not Git Push. These are the steps I followed. I tried various versions of this actually, but nothing worked.

```
git config --global user.email "xxx@gmail.com"
git config --global user.name "abc"

git pull https://PAT@github.com/repo.git HEAD:dev    
git add $PROXYNAME
git commit -m 'Auto-checkin of $PROXYNAME proxy to Git'
git show-ref
git push https://PAT@github.com/repo.git HEAD:dev
```

The above worked when the push / pull had HEAD:master at the end.
This is the error I have been getting each time.

```
To https://github.com/repo.git
 ! [rejected]        HEAD -> dev (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://***@github.com/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Edited to add:
I have also tried with a checkout command - to checkout that dev branch, and no luck!
Result of git remote -v:

```
origin  https://github.com/repo (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/repo (push)
```

The latest error am getting is below:

```
error: src refspec dev does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://***@github.com/repo.git'
```

Could anyone please let me know what I need to do to get this working. This seems to be a recurring issue for me now :(

Comment: You should make a git pull before you push... You also can try with git fetch.

Comment: Yeah.. that was the first try. Sorry I posted the final trial here. And it didn't work either. I edited the post and corrected that here now.

Comment: post in the question the result of `git remote -v`

Comment: @DudiBoy I have updated it now

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to configure `git remote` to your correct repository.

The result of `git remote -v` should refer to your current directory remote association.

Start with `git remote --help`

Especially:

> git remote set-url [--push]   [] git remote
>
> set-url --add [--push]

Here is a good [tutorial on git remote](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing).